# Find isn't finding exact match in a string in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, find

I wrote a code in vba in which if I enter a string in cell `B8` then it will match in other worksheet ranged `A6:A500`. My finding text is `Carlos Leather Fashion*Lefties*Alex*Mid Blue`. And there is a string in `A6` which is `Carlos Leather Fashions*Lefties*Alex*Mid Blue`. So, it is not matching because there is an extra 's' in fashion abbreviation. But my vba code is showing Found in this case also. Here is my code -

```
Dim helper As String
    
helper = Cells(8, 2).Value
    
Dim paymentStatusSheet As Worksheet
Set paymentStatusSheet = Worksheets("Payment-Summary")
'--------------------------------------------------------------Set the Payment status worksheet
    
If paymentStatusSheet.Range("A6:A500").Find(What:=helper, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    
    MsgBox "Not Found"
    
Else
    MsgBox "Found"
    
End If
```

Help pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arise because of `Range.Find()` seeing the asterisk `*` character as wildcard, which match any characters.  The search string `Fashion*` therefore matches `Fashions*`

A quick solution is to escape the search pattern.  Excel treats `~*` in the search string as a single asterisk character.  Therefore a quick fix to your specific use case would be:

```
Dim helper As String
    
helper = Cells(8, 2).Value
helper = Replace(helper, "*", "~*")  '<-- Note this new line
    
Dim paymentStatusSheet As Worksheet
Set paymentStatusSheet = Worksheets("Payment-Summary")
'--------------------------------------------------------------Set the Payment status worksheet
    
If paymentStatusSheet.Range("A6:A500").Find(What:=helper, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    
    MsgBox "Not Found"
    
Else
    MsgBox "Found"
    
End If
```

Here, I did not take care of other wildcards, i.e. `?` and `~`.  You may need to escape those if you foresee them in your search strings.

Comment: Thanks Bro! it Helped. And kindly vote my question if you understand it in first time. Actually I am new in vba. So, If anyone didn't vote me then I will not be able to ask question after a time. Thanks again!